# How can I use validation set for hyper parameter tuning in a direct forecast time series problem?

Tags: time-series, python, random-forest, validation

I have a time series dataset with features corresponding to the same dates as the target. I'm using these features, along with date features such as month, week number etc to build a multivariate model which predicts the target using Random forest.

The model is a one step direct forecast, as in I predict the target value for 1 month in future, and then use it to train and predict the 2nd month in future in a rolling format for 6 months.

Currently I have 24 months of data as training, 6 months validation and 6 months for testing.
My current approach is that I use the 24 months data to train and predict 6 months rolling and use these 6 months against my validation set to measure the error, say MAPE while I tune the hyper parameters to see which combination gives me the minimum MAPE with the validation set.
I have started wondering if this is a correct approach to be used with a direct forecast scenario? Are there any suggestions or changes that I need to make?

Comment: Maybe I misinterpret something but how many data-points do you have? 36? What is dimensionality of your dataset?

Comment: To give you more context, I'm trying to predict sales value for a product in future 6 months. I have considered 10 products similar to this product. Hence I have 10x24(similar product history) + 1x24(history of product to be forecasted) = 264 data points in training. Validation I have 6 data points and testing I have 6 data points.